# how to replace the while by a cursor?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I would like to replace the while loop below by cursor, I tried many example but I did not succeed up to now , can you help me on this please ?

```
set @tableboundary =( select count(*) as counts from @From_T)
 while @counter < @tableboundary
begin
set @Enti = (select Entities from @From_T where id= @counter)
    Insert into @Temp_Tamale ( Entities) select  value FROM MarMo.dbo.udf_ParseInto(@Enti, ',', '', '')
    set @counter = @counter + 1 
end
```

Comment: And for ***what database*** is this?? MySql? Oracle? Postgres? Interbase? SQL Server? Db2? Something else entirely????

Comment: I am using SQL, it is a stored procedure

Comment: SQL is just the **query language** - again, this is still no **database product**!

Comment: As described below, a single query can do this job, anyways imho using a cursor will not get you around a `WHILE`-Loop.... `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to use a cursor when you can use a single SQL statement?

```
Insert into @Temp_Tamale (Entities)
    select value
    from @From_T t cross apply
         MarMo.dbo.udf_ParseInto(t.Entities, ',', '', '');
```